# How to hook into submittable state of form validation

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, forms, vue.js

In a vue project i have a basic form with an email and password input, which are both required. Now without any code written, the form prevents the user from clicking submit when a required field is not met, then displays an error message.

```
<form @submit="loginSubmit()">
      <div class="grid gap-4 mb-6 md:grid-cols-2">
        <div class="col-span-2">
          <input
            type="email"
            v-model="email"
            required
          />
        </div>
        <div class="col-span-2">
          <input
            type="password"
            v-model="password"
            required
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <BaseButton
        type="submit"
        title="Login"
      >
     
    </form>
```

that means there must be some kind of prop in the form logic that evaluates the whole form as either submittable or not submittable. It would be very useful to be able to hook into that, because eg to apply css based on the submittable state id have to write sth like

```
 get isLoginPossible() {
    return this.email !== '' && this.password !== ''
  }
```

which doesnt event check if the email type is met (while the form does)
Is there any way to hook into the value that defined if the form is submittable or not and use it?

Comment: You would probably need `@submit.prevent` to handle the submission yourself. `required` can also be removed if you want to handle that yourself. This could be a good starting point: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html#form-input-bindings

Comment: Thats custom validation, what i want is a hook into the basic validation state

Comment: There is nothing tied to HTML directly. The API has nothing to do with Vue and is quite basic. Either use the HTML defaults or make it custom with Vue. You can also use [pattern](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp) to have a bit more options but it will still not be brought back into Vue.